# Search Dataframe in r for string using predefined table and add corresponding column

Tags: python, r, regex, string, dataframe

Here is the sample data frame

```
     # create a sample test scenarios
data <- rbind(c("Cisco Catalyst 3850 Series Ethernet Stackable Switch","ports"), c("Cisco 7200 Series Routers", "Ports"),
              c("Cisco Catalyst 3560-CX Series Switches", "Ports"), c("Data Center Switches", "Ports"), 
              c("SW_3560_IDF1d_1879.ccs.ccctov.org", "Ports")) # sample data
```

String to value table

```
3850 - 50
7200 - 2
3560 - 60
Data Center - 240
3560 - 60
```

Final output sample:

```
finaldata <- rbind(c("Cisco Catalyst 3850 Series Ethernet Stackable Switch","ports", 50), c("Cisco 7200 Series Routers", "Ports", 2),
          c("Cisco Catalyst 3560-CX Series Switches", "Ports", 60), c("Data Center Switches", "Ports", 240), 
          c("SW_3560_IDF1d_1879.ccs.ccctgov.org", "Ports", 60)) # sample data
```

Appreciate your help or guidance!

Comment: Just an initial point, what you have in `data` is a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use some regex and `recode` from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
newColumn <- recode(sub(".*(3850|7200|3560|Data Center).*", "\\1", data[,1]), 
                    `3850` = 50, 
                    `7200` = 2,
                    `3560` = 60,
                    `Data Center` = 240)

cbind(data, newColumn)

                                                                    newColumn
[1,] "Cisco Catalyst 3850 Series Ethernet Stackable Switch" "ports" "50"     
[2,] "Cisco 7200 Series Routers"                            "Ports" "2"      
[3,] "Cisco Catalyst 3560-CX Series Switches"               "Ports" "60"     
[4,] "Data Center Switches"                                 "Ports" "240"    
[5,] "SW_3560_IDF1d_1879.ccs.ccctov.org"                    "Ports" "60"
```

A slightly different way to do it:

```
codes <- sub(".*(3850|7200|3560|Data Center).*", "\\1", data[,1])
newCodes <- list(`3850` = 50, `7200` = 2, `3560` = 60, `Data Center` = 240)
cbind(data, recode(codes, !!!newCodes))
```

Comment: Nice answer. Quick query - is there a way to make `recode()` use a lookup table/named vector as input?

Comment: @thelatemail see my edit, I'm not sure if this is what you asked for.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, cheers! I imagine being able to feed in a big `list` might be helpful when you have many categories to recode, rather than typing them all out as a long call.

Comment: @Jilber Urbina, thank you so much! you are really awesome!